# Timer doesn't start after the exe startup

Tags: c#, timer, console, startup

I am using C#, visual studio community 2013 and Windows 8.1 Pro

I did a test program in c#(console) to create a file txt after some time(1 minute) also I did that the exe starts when the user login, This works fine except when I reboot my pc.

When I reboot my pc, the program execute successful but after 1 minute and more doesn't create the file txt. I can see in the task manager that the exe is running.

I am thinking that the timer doesn't work when It starts of this way(login), but I dont know why.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: The console always is hidden.

Thanks.

Code Main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegisterInStartup(true);

        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 60000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        // Hide
        var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);
        while(true);

    }
```

RegisterInStartup:

```
private static void RegisterInStartup(bool isChecked)
    {
        RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
        if (isChecked)
        {
            registryKey.SetValue("ApplicationName", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
        }
        else
        {
            registryKey.DeleteValue("ApplicationName");
        }
        registryKey.Close();
    }
```

event timer:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //only for testing
        StreamWriter objWriter;
        objWriter = new StreamWriter(@"testing.txt");
        objWriter.Write("now");
        objWriter.Close();
    }
```

Comment: try adding a try catch statement with a msgbox popup. See if any exception is thrown

Comment: `while(true);` nice way to  burn your CPU..

Comment: Your code cant be compiled since the `GetConsoleWindow` and `ShowWindow` are WIN API methods.

Comment: How are you calling this? I'd be curious if the context of it running via task / startup is writing that file relative to the calling application. Try defining the full literal path for the file...?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a Working Directory issue. Try using an [absolute path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Absolute_and_relative_paths) instead of just "testing.txt".

Comment: @Steve Thanks!!, gives me this error: System.UnathorizedAccessException: Access denied to path: C:/Windows/System32/testing.txt ...........etc,

Comment: How say @itsme86  I will put the absolute path

Comment: @L.B yes sorry, That is only a test, the final code is with Application.run() and others code.

Comment: 1) You shouldn't be showing GUI in a console app 2) System.Timers.Timer is the wrong timer if the intent _was_ for a GUI app 3) You should use `ShowDialog()` and not `ShowWindow()` because `while(true);` will block the message pump from being processed

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales there you go. You don't have write permission for system folder without admin right. Which is the default environment for application started by system

Comment: @Steve , my project is in G:/projects/ and not in C:, why I would need permission?

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales Read the error message carefully. it is trying to write to `C:/Windows/System32/` because it is your application's startup path.... you can use for example `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` or `Path.GetTempPath()`

Comment: @L.B I solved the problem with absolute path(string "G:/projects/..."), but I dont want write a absolute path, you have reason I will use your recommendation.